# Fineuploader initial file list - displaying file size

Tags: json, fine-uploader

I have the inital file list working well, but i was wondering if it's possible to display the size of the uploaded image?

My json returns the "size" param as per the documentation, but it does not seem to be used. What i was looking for was the filesize to be displayed next to the links, similar to what is done when the file is actually uploaded.

I am using the standard thumbnail template, which i can see has the following element:
    
Can this be populated with the file size on retrieval of the inital file list?

Comment: Please show the exact response your server returns when Fine Uploader sends its GET initial file list request.

Comment: `[{"name":"IMAG0170.JPG","uuid":"45cdb065-8f2a-4ca2-9e2d-163e34f984b3","size":"1216689","id":"56","client_id": "73","thumbnailUrl":"\/client-images\/45cdb065-8f2a-4ca2-9e2d-163e34f984b3\/thumb_IMAG0170.JPG"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as is, but you've uncovered an issue in Fine Uploader.  The workaround is to set contribute the following option:

```
display: {
    fileSizeOnSubmit: true
}
```

This issue is being tracked and will be fixed in a 4.3.1 hotfix release, most likely today.

https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1130

Comment: This has been fixed in 4.3.1, which we just released.